# How can I use Javascript to allow navigation between sections using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I wish to allow **navigation between the posts** on my blog using the `j` and `k` keys on the keyboard (similar to that which Facebook and Tumblr use). Each post has it's own div class if that's any help.

- How do I go about doing this using HTML/CSS/Javascript?

I tried using [this blog post](http://blog.jrmoran.com/keyboard-navigation-keynav-jquery-plugin/) but, honestly, I have no clue where to even start with **Javascript**!

Comment: Listen for the keypress on the window. Find current scroll position, find the next/prev section based on position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgg20cej/)

A couple of things:

1. Because of the way JSFiddle works when it's loaded you'll need to
   click on one of the "blog posts" so that window is focused.
2. K moves to the next post, J moves to the previous post.
3. There is NO error handling. It will crash and stop working if you try to go too far up or down. I had to leave something for you to
   do, right? ;-)

.

The JQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 74)
        {
            $(".current").prev().addClass("current");
            $(".current").eq(1).removeClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top
            }, 250);
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 75)
        {
            $(".current").next().addClass("current");
            $(".current").eq(0).removeClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top
            }, 250);   
        }
});
```

Comment: Aside from the crashing, this is perfect!

Comment: FYI the crashing is because there's no 'next' div to assign the value to when you reach the end. You could just check that there is a div before trying to assign the value (and the same going backwards) and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can come up with this is using Javascript with Html anchors.

Use Javascript to listen for specific keys and a condition for when the key is pressed. Html anchors will be used as an "beacon" for the javascript navigation.

First read up on anchors and understand how they work. Then try to create a javascript code that fits your requirement and take advantage of the anchors.